# Can the following be done with Organic Groups?

Tags: users, organic-groups

I have a menu tab called "College" and what I'm trying to do is, when one user logs in he will be able to see information about the college regarding him.

So I have 2 colleges called CIT and UCC and I want users going to CIT to be able just to view the CIT page when they click on "college" from the menu and users going to UCC to be able to view just the UCC page when they click on college. I want students to be able to just view the information and one user to be able to edit it.

I've been searching how to do it for a while and was wondering if this is something I can do with organic groups or is this a completely different thing?

Any HELP be greatly appreciated!!!!

Comment: "Colleges" are nodes? How many? Are you describing restricted access to different pages per user role? "Students" are user entities?

Comment: I am very new to drupal so not sure what you are asking but I would like for a one group of users to be able to click "College" from navigation menu and view certain information. Then another group of users to be able to view different information!  I was wondering is this possible ? So basically for 2 different pages to show up when college is clicked depending on the user

Comment: Use OG to control access per college(s) based on user roles. Assuming that a college is a node and a student is a user, turn the college node type into an OG and create user roles per college. Then set up the OG accordingly. Since you are new to OG and Drupal would be a bit hard to get accustomed with the terminology but fortunately there is a lot of good [documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/861418)